# Open external subtitles on mpv on Linux without terminal

Tags: linux, subtitles

On Windows, if I just drag a srt file on to a playing video, the subtitles are displayed. On Linux, the dragging doesn't work. Now, mpv is my default player, so I just double click on the video file to play it. But I can't add subtitles. And I don't want to open my terminal everytime I play a video.

Comment: And so many people claim mpv is better than vlc??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MPV help page's subtitle section](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#subtitles):

You need to put `sub-auto`, and likely `sub-paths` in your mpv.conf file (see link for examples). I'm not aware of any support for "drag and drop" subtitles addition in MPV.

Comment: In mpv version 0.23.0 (Debian) drag and dropping a `.srt` file seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, create a file mpv.conf in  ~/.config/mpv and add the following lines:

--sub-auto=all

--sub-file-paths=sub:subtitles:<any_other_folder_with_subtitle_files>

you can add names of folder where subtitles are (could be a subdirectory within the folder of the movie).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I made a folder containing just the video file and the subtitle file and modified their names so that they are the same. I then played the video file on MPV and pressed <kbd>v</kbd> to show the subtitles. It worked!

BTW, I'm using MPV on Linux Mint 18.

Answer (score 0):

I made a GUI so you can use it to make a MPV configuration file and play movies with subtitle using it (for GNU/Linux) :

[MPV SUB CONF](https://github.com/zeynaliAli/MPV-Sub-Configure)